# Can I rotate the x axis by 45 degrees? Trying to make tephigram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to have the y axis as it but rotate my x axis by 45 degrees. cannot seem to find any help about this online. cheers in advance for any help.

code is as follows

```
t = nwp.get('T','1000 hPa')

lon,lat = nwp.grid()
a,b = common.gridij3(174.,-41.,lon,lat)

pressure=[1000,950,925,850,700,600,500,400,300,250,150,100]

tt=[]
td=[]
tw=[]
for level in pressure:
    tt.append(nwp.get('T','%i hPa' %level)[a,b]) # % means add hPa to value taken from level list
    td.append(nwp.get('TD','%i hPa' %level)[a,b])
    tw.append(nwp.get('TW','%i hPa' %level)[a,b])

print '---Temperatures---'
for t in tt:
    print t
print '---Dew points---'
for t in td:
    print t
print '---Wet bulb temperatures---'
for t in tw:
    print t


#invert pressure axis
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
#need to know how to rotate x axis by 45

plt.xlabel('Temperature K')
plt.ylabel('Pressure hPa')

plt.yscale('log')

plt.plot(tt,pressure,'r',label='Temp')
plt.plot(td,pressure,label='Dew Point')
plt.plot(tw,pressure,'g',label='Wet Bulb Temperature')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: "cannot seem to find any help about this online" That's a strong statement you have here! What did you look for? Please explain your problem rather than pasting lines of codes with "I need to do that", that will help those who will try to help you.

Comment: 1.4 adds support for skew axes.  Also look into wcs_axes (look up the scipy2014 talk)

Comment: sorry for my noob-ness here but im essentially trying to make a tephigram or skew-t plot. In essence its tempreture vs pressure(log scale)

however the temperature axis is rotated by 45 degrees roughly. I was wondering if its easy to just plot x,y variables then just rotate the x axis. 

I have got some code that will take in my original x,y values and churn out new x,y values that when plotted will represent what the plot should look like if the x axis were rotated by 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which direction, do you have the degrees for your variable?

I envision something like a basic if/else:

If your new axis goes past 360, take 360 - your axis then rotate - difference and add that to 0.

// pseudocode

if x-axis + rotate < 360
 x-axis = x-axis + 45
else
 x-axis = 0 + (45 - (360 - x-axis))

Answer (score 0):

I found half a dozen useful pages by Googling "matplotlib skew-T";

the general approach, exemplified by [Plotting straight line on semilog plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666206/plotting-straight-line-on-semilog-plot-with-matplotlib) seems to be to calculate an appropriate x-offset for each data point, rather than rotating the axis.

You might also find https://github.com/tchubb/SkewT useful.

Comment: cheers for this. it seems the best approach is to recalculate the off set for each x value and re plot it on a normal xy plane. thus it will plot the points as if the x axis is off by 45 degrees.

I have obtained some code that does this: